# Restriction of a covering map to a subspace

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a covering map and let $Y_0 \subset Y$. Show that $p|:p^{-1}(Y_0)\rightarrow Y_0$ is a covering map.
Hint: Show first that if $V\subset Y$ is well-covered by $p$, then $Y_0\cap V$ is well-covered by $p|:p^{-1}(Y_0)\rightarrow Y_0$.

All I've got so far is the definition of a covering map written out. I can't even seem to use the hint given.

Comment: If you have proven the hint and since $Y_0\subset Y$, what can you say about covering $Y_0\cap Y_0$ by $p|$?

Comment: Is that a typo? Should it be $Y_0\cap V$?

Comment: In particular, the hint's statement implies $V=Y_0\subset Y$. I have not figured out a proof yet, but the statement seems straight forward (if you keep the relative topology in mind).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $p$ is a covering map, there exists an open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ of $X$ by evenly covered sets $U_{\alpha}$. That is, for all $\alpha$, $p^{-1}(U_{\alpha}) = \bigsqcup_{i \in I} V^i_{\alpha}$ for some index set $I$, and the restriction $p:V^i_{\alpha} \to U_{\alpha}$ for any particular $i$ is a homeomorphism. Since the $U_{\alpha}$ cover $X$, $\{U_{\alpha} \cap Y_0\}$ is an open cover of $Y_0$. Additionally, for all $\alpha$, $p^{-1}(U_{\alpha} \cap Y_0) = p^{-1}(U_{\alpha}) \cap p^{-1}(Y_0) = \bigsqcup_{i \in I} V^i_{\alpha} \cap p^{-1}(Y_0)$. $p:V^i_{\alpha} \to U_{\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism, so the restriction $p: V_{\alpha}^i \cap p^{-1}(Y_0) \to p(V_{\alpha}^i \cap p^{-1}(Y_0))$ is also a homeomorphism. But $p(V_{\alpha}^i \cap p^{-1}(Y_0)) = U_{\alpha} \cap Y_0$ since a homeomorphism is in particular bijective, so the $U_{\alpha} \cap Y_0$ are evenly covered. Hence $Y_0$ has an open cover by evenly covered sets, so the restriction $p:p^{-1}(Y_0) \to Y_0$ is a covering map.